# What model or brand, for test equipment of lots of IO's

Tags: test-equipment, data-acquisition

Can someone give me a type or a brand of **test equipment**.
I need something bigger and possibly faster than what I am currently using which is :

test 8 pcb's and simulate a machine all at the same time that represents **368 voltage (20-50VDC) reading inputs** and **168 relay outputs (500mA)** and possibly **some 0-8amps current readings**. Also maybe the technology also offers a PSU around 50 amps, 20-50VDC, but we can continue using our B&K MR25080

I am already testing 1 board at a time and it works very well but it is too small and a bit slow cause the inputs are contacts multiplexers and are complex multi-usage cards, and the setup is :

-- B&K MR25080 remote controlled PSU.
-- Keithley 2750 with 5 expansions cards.

Price is not very important, I mostly need something easy to communicate with, to serial control from scripts, reliable, maybe relays that I can switch when they fail, rack mountable.

Many thanks,

Mike.

Comment: Haven't checked lately, but a decade+ ago or so the NI had a nice portfolio of general purpose hardware and software called LabView that is used to interface with that hardware, perform tasks and and make custom user interfaces. It is costly though, but you say it's not important.

Comment: @Mike More you can send an email to me to sales@kalliodesigns.com for some idea exchange.

Comment: We decided to use a Keysight 34980A with 8 cards in it, we have a cards setup for 400 1-wire inputs and 192 relay outputs, it is perfect.
Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 2):

At that scale my experience is that it's easier to design custom tester electronics and an "interlayer" circuit board, that may hold test pins and help with connecting everything. I find such solution easiest to build, maintain and have most control over.

Otherwise the unnecessary connectors, wirings, amount of separate instruments etc makes the setup too bulky and prone to faults.

If you want to go with less "custom" parts and pick the off-the-shelf option: National Instruments PXI -system can handle the mentioned inputs and much more and has good control on timing etc. Such a modular system would be the go to solution for many.